# Exclude directory completely from google search

Tags: indexing, seo, robots.txt, google-search

So I want to exclude a whole directory (and its subfolders) from being indexed by any search engine. Lets imagine my domain is called "**example.com**" and the directory "**directory-to-exclude**"

Now when I enter the following keywords

**directory-to-exclude example**  (without .com)

I am getting this as a google result:

> **directory-to-exclude - example**
>
> *example.com/directory-to-exclude/*
>
> A description for this result is not available because of this site's
>   robots.txt – learn more.

So it DOES show up, even though the content is hidden and not being indexed. But I want to prevent google COMPLETELY from showing it.
Now, sure one would have to know the name of my directory to google that, but it could be guessed (and dont want to rename it cryptically)

What I did so far, is put these lines in my robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10

# Directories
Disallow: /directory-to-exclude/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: http://www.example.com/directory-to-exclude/
Disallow: http://example.com/directory-to-exclude/
Disallow: /directory-to-exclude/
```

Still, no success. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

As google allready wrote their meta description for your site:

"A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more."

So your robots.txt infact is right. Nevertheless if there are links pointing to that directory or google thinks its actauly quiet important it will crawl the page nevertheless. If you want to get rid of that you can use the noindex tag on every page within that directory:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added that. Lets see if google removes it now from its index... I'll update here, if they do.

Comment: You can try to speed this up by going into your google webmaster account (if you have one, if not you should get one, its free) and use the URL Removal tool:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

Comment: Yeah, had already done that some months ago. thanx for the reminder, did it again now.

Comment: You need to remove the `Disallow` rule from `robots.txt` so that Googlebot can crawl the URL and see the `noindex`.  If you continue to disallow the page, Google won't know it shouldn't index it.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect all traffic to other directory and wait for reindexing with `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 /old-page/ https://www.example.com/
```